# Using QFileSystemWatcher from a console application

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use QFileSystemWatcher from a console application, with my current approach I'm not getting any signals that are omitted. Can anyone point out what is wrong with this setup?

```
static duk_ret_t automation_watch(duk_context *ctx)
{
    int argc = 0; char** argv = 0;
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    bool retval = false;
    QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(&app);
    qDebug() << QDir::current().absolutePath();
    watcher->addPath(QDir::current().absolutePath());
    retval = QObject::connect(watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged, [](const QString& a) {
        printf(a.toStdString().c_str());
        printf("\r\n");
        return 0;
    }); 
    assert(retval == true);

    retval = QObject::connect(watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged , [](const QString& a) {
        printf(a.toStdString().c_str());
        printf("\r\n");
        return 0;
    });
    assert(retval == true);

    app.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you reword "my current approach I'm getting any signals that are omited." please.  I completely don't understand it.  I suggest you break it into several short sentences.  Start by changing the comma to a full stop.

Comment: Is there a "not" missing?  Should it be "omitted" (left out), or "emitted" (sent out)?

Comment: did you try it without the mutex and wait_condition?

Comment: Can you verify that `addPath` returns `true`? Otherwise it will not generate events for your watched directory... Also, your `printf` might not show up because of buffering. Make sure to print a newline to flush.

Comment: @MartinBonner sorry fixed the spelling/grammar.

Comment: @Botje I updated the code to include asserts, addPath returns true.

Comment: @Amfassis i removed the conditions/locks, see updated code.

Comment: @LawrenceKok no, your posted code checks the return value of `QObject::connect` instead of `addPath`

Comment: asserted on both, same results! doesn't emit any signal. @Botje